# I want to move one marker to another

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, folium

So I have used Python (Folium) library in Python to get the maps and markers. How can I move markers? I attached an image. If you have any other way to do, you can also help me, I need this for my project.
[image]

Map Created Using (Folium). I have searched different libraries but nothing worked. My problem is totally based on Geo tracking.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to drag the markers, foliums `Marker` class currently accepts a `draggable` argument: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.map.Marker

```
m = folium.Map()
folium.Marker((lat, lon), draggable=True).add_to(m)
```

If you mean making an animation, you could consider using the `TimestampedGeoJson` plugin, though it might need some effort to get it running:

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/Plugins.ipynb#Timestamped-GeoJSON

Comment: I guess one can use something like BeautifulSoup to edit an html file outputted from Folium and add that `draggable: true` automatically.

Comment: folium currently accepts the draggable argument, I'll update my answer

Comment: How to get the coordinates changed? How do I change the coordinates on the marker, so if I drag the marker, then I want the markers coordinates to be save to a variable.

Comment: I want to save the new value of the draggable marker.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")
IconUrl = "https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1465/PNG/128/604bullettrain_100995.png"

m = folium.Map([-3.049648, 53.4372116], zoom_start = 10)



# step 1
TempFeature = []
# do the following command for each marker 
temp_df = df.query(f"Marker_id == {1}")

TempFeature.append({ 'type': 'Feature',

                 'geometry': { 'type': 'LineString',

#                               example coordinates 
#                               [
#                                (-3.049648, 53.4372116),
#                                (-3.04967139134615, 53.4372056616587),
#                                (-3.04972986971154, 53.4371908158053),
#                                 .
#                                 .
#                                 .
#                                (-3.04972986971154, 53.4371908158053),
#                               ] 
                              'coordinates': list(zip(temp_df['Longitude'],temp_df['Latitude']))
                             },




                     'properties':{ 
                                     'icon': 'marker',
                                    'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': IconUrl, 'iconSize': [20, 20], },

                                     # time must be like the following format : '2018-12-01T05:53:00'
                                     'times': temp_df['Timetable'] ,
                                     'popup': #html
                      }})



# step 2
TimestampedGeoJson({
                        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                        'features': TempFeature,
                        }
                        , period='P1D' 
                      ).add_to(m)

m
```